# Co-author in footline, Berkley theme

Tags: beamer

I am using `Berkley` theme. I want to add the name of co-authors in footnote in the title page.

How can I do it ?

I used `\footline{}`, `\footnotetext{}` but in vain.

```
{
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>


\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
%
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{95,10,10}
%
\definecolor{header_footer_color}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=header_footer_color}
\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{fg=white,bg=header_footer_color}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}         
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}



\definecolor{rowcolor}{rgb}{0.65,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{blockcolor}{RGB}{229,191,191}




\title{title}  
\subtitle{more text}
\author{author1}
\institute{inst1} 
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
%\footline{auth1,auth2,auth3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dib, please provide the community with at least a shell of a `beamer` presentation under your `Berkley` theme. It'll make absorption of content *much* easier and get answers your way *far* quicker.

Comment: This works (but it's not pretty): `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\author{The Author}
\title{The title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\footnote{Co-author1}
\footnote{Co-author2}
\footnote{Co-author3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina can you please write an answer or should we close the question?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; I defined a `\blfootnote` to have footnotes without marker:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Berkeley} 

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\author{The Author} 
\title{The title} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame} 
\maketitle 
\blfootnote{Co-Authors:} 
\blfootnote{Name One -- Name Two -- Name Three} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]